# Radio button selected after submit a form

Tags: wordpress, radio-button

I have a form where i used radio buttom and when radio buttom is selected and submit the buttom the value is pass but radio buttom not selected. My code for the radio buttom in the form is written bellow.

```
echo '<form name="posts_form" id="post_form" method="post" action="">';
echo $displaycategory = get_option('posts_displaycategory');

echo '<p>Display Date:<br><input type="radio"  value="YES"';
echo $posts_displaydate . '" name="posts_displaydate" id="posts_displaydate"  /> YES</p>';

echo '<input type="radio" value="NO"';
echo $posts_displaydate . '" name="posts_displaydate" id="posts_displaydate" /> NO</p>';
```

Now i want to select the radio buttom when i select the radio buttom.Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question. "Now i want to select the radio buttom when i select the radio buttom.Thank you". What does that mean?

Comment: apart from readability of the question try with the unique id as well for posts_displaydate

Comment: When i select a radio button and submit the form, the value pass but i want the radio buttom also have selected as i selected whether it already submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the condition with $posts_displaydate like below or write down the full code so i will write.

```
if($posts_displaydate=='YES') echo "checked"; 
if($posts_displaydate=='NO') echo "checked";
```